# Angular Material, Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-material, angular6

I am developing UI using angular material and Bootstrap in Angular 6. For Some components I am using Bootstrap for Styling and for others angular Matrerial. But in angular material I am facing below issue.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YHou can try to add style to your input. Like this:

```
input {
 outline: none
}
```

If dont work try :

```
input {
 outline: none!important
}
```